# SYMFONY - Display an input according to the value of a drop-down list

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, dynamic-forms

I'm learning how to use Symfony and I'm stuck on a form.
I have a drop-down list, and depending on the choice, I would like to display an input.
I have been looking for a solution for more than 4 days, but I can't find anything, so I come here to ask for your help

When I select "Lycéen.ne" in this dropdown list : [dropdownList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3e5K.png),
I would like to display the input "Lycée" : [inputLycee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwUbz.png)

I know there are FormEvent, but I don't really understand how it works and how to use JS to show or hide inputs

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: If you want to keep the form completely configured via symfony, you'll need to submit the form with javascript and re-render it with the server rendered response. A starting point (with example) would be: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep use Symfony to render the entire form and then use a bit of JS and CSS to hide or show the field that should be shown dynamically. Here's an example using plain JS:

```js
let foo = document.getElementById("foo");
let bar = document.getElementById("bar");

foo.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    if (event.target.value === 'two') {
    bar.style.display = 'inline'; // Show the element.
  } else {
    bar.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the element.
  }
});
```

```css
#bar {
  display: none; // Hide the element initially. 
}
```

```html
<select name="foo" id="foo">
  <option value="one">Do not show</option>
  <option value="two">Show</option>
</select>

<input name="bar" id="bar" value="" placeholder="type something here..." >
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it was possible to use Symfony with JS in this way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is really doable with symfony, I think its more of a jquery question :

```
    $('#listid').change(function(event){
      $('#inputid').toggle($(this).val() == 'Lycéen.ne');
    });
```